# Passing list of row numbers into 2 dataframes, labeling, and adding to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is all in python pandas.

I have a list of integers called different_rows that holds the row number of each row that has differences between 2 dataframes. In this case a dataframe holding data from netezza and a dataframe holding data from oracle. (prepped_net_df, prepped_ora_df)

I am trying to pass in the row number to the original dataframes to get the row of data from the data frame. I want to able to add a tag to that row to know which dataframe it came from (i.e. netezza or oracle) and then i want to add that row (series) to a new dataframe. That int from different_rows needs to be passed to both into the netezza and oracle dataframes.

The following code works but the problem is it runs really slow.

I have a 2 part question.

1. What would be the best approach for testing which one of the lines is causing this to run slow?
2. Is there a way to optimize this code. This works fine for 10-1000 rows but sometimes i have data frames that are tens of thousands of rows.

Thank you for your time. Any help is appreciated

```
net_dict = {'ACCTG_DATE': ['2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-02 00:00:00', '2012-01-03 00:00:00', '2012-01-04 00:00:00' ], 'JRNL_ID_NO': ['00349-CAS','00350-CAS','00351-CAS','00352-CAS' ], 'JRNL_SEQ_NO': [43970,43971,43972,43973], 'ACCT_CODE': [8500016,8500017,8500018,8500019], 'BAL_BOOK_CODE': [8591,8592,8593,8594], 'PROD_CODE': ['12F7', '12F8', '12F9', '12G0'], 'SUSPENSE_SEQ_NO': [0, 1, 2, 3 ], 'TRAN_AMT': [8900.29, 8901.29, 8902.29, 8903.29], 'CENTER_CODE': ['', '', '', ''], 'BASIS_TYPE': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'UPDATE_TSTP':['2011-12-31 00:00:00', '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-02 00:00:00', '2012-01-03 00:00:00']}
ora_dict = {'ACCTG_DATE': ['2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-02 00:00:00', '2012-01-04 00:00:00', '2012-01-04 00:00:00' ], 'JRNL_ID_NO': ['00349-CAS','00350-CAS','00351-CAS','00353-CAS' ], 'JRNL_SEQ_NO': [43970,43971,43972,43973], 'ACCT_CODE': [8500016,8500017,8500018,8500019], 'BAL_BOOK_CODE': [8591,8592,8593,8594], 'PROD_CODE': ['12F7', '12F8', '12F9', '12G0'], 'SUSPENSE_SEQ_NO': [0, 1, 2, 3 ], 'TRAN_AMT': [8900.29, 8901.29, 8903, 8903.29], 'CENTER_CODE': ['', '', '', ''], 'BASIS_TYPE': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'UPDATE_TSTP':['2011-12-31 00:00:00', '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-02 00:00:00', '2012-01-03 00:00:00']}

different_rows = [2, 3]

prepped_net_df = pd.DataFrame(data=net_dict)
prepped_ora_df = pd.DataFrame(data=ora_dict)
prepped_net_df.infer_objects()
prepped_ora_df.infer_objects()

row_compare_df = pd.DataFrame()

if different_rows != None:
    start = time.clock()
    for val in different_rows:
        print('processed: val - ', val)
        net_series = prepped_net_df.iloc[val]
        net_series.loc['Source'] = "Netezza"
        row_compare_df = row_compare_df.append(net_series)
        ora_series = prepped_ora_df.iloc[val]
        ora_series.loc['Source'] = "Oracle"
        row_compare_df = row_compare_df.append(ora_series)
    end = time.clock() - start
    print("Cell has run completely. It took " + str(round(end, 2)) + " seconds")    
else:
    print("There were no rows reported with differences")
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Have added a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Sorry i am a newb. Thanks for the link it helped. Just to add, different_rows is gathered by running the two dataframes through a function that returns a list of ints that represents the index of the different rows. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to loop over your list. All you need is pass he list and get the rows from your dfs and then concat them as below:

```
net = prepped_net_df.iloc[different_rows].assign(Source='Netezza')
ora = prepped_ora_df.iloc[different_rows].assign(Source='Oracle')
row_compare_df = pd.concat([net, ora], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi Harv, Thank you for your help. I understand your answer and i see that will speed things up a ton. 2 things that are a little different, in my example the indexes are preserved. For this i just removed ignore_index=True from the pd.concat method. The other difference is that in the code provided in the row_comare_df Dataframe i would end up with alternating rows. i.e. Netezza row with index = 2 followed by Oracle row with index = 2 and so forth. Was thinking now that i have indexes preserved would the best way to do be to sort of the index, or is there a way i can do this as par of concat?

Comment: @hfrog713, you are correct. I added `ignore_index=True`, just before posting the answer. You can simply remove it if you want to preserve the original indexers and then sort them so that all the entries from two dfs will be ordered accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answered all of my questions and also taught me a bit about posting questions on SO.

Comment: Glad to help. @hfrog713. Happy coding.